# Bootstrap Chef on Vagrant Box

Tags: ruby, vagrant, knife, chef

I'm trying to bootstrap a Vagrant box using hosted chef server.

```
knife bootstrap testbed001.me --sudo -x root -N "testbed001"
```

However, the command throws an error:

```
Bootstrapping Chef on testbed001.me
testbed001.me /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mixlib/log.rb:97:in `level=': Log level must be one of :debug, :info, :warn, :error, or :fatal (ArgumentError)
testbed001.me   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/application.rb:113:in `configure_logging'
testbed001.me   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/application/client.rb:213:in `configure_logging'
testbed001.me   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/application.rb:63:in `reconfigure'
testbed001.me   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/application/client.rb:168:in `reconfigure'
testbed001.me   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef/application.rb:68:in `run'
testbed001.me   from /usr/bin/chef-client:25:in `<main>'
```

My `knife.rb` file:

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
.
.
.
```

I've tried to bootstrap another node hosted on DigitalOcean and got no issues. I'm using version `11.8.2`. Anyone experience the same?

Answer (score 1):

Also seen in [CHEF-3610](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3610), your knife/chef version might be 11.8.2 indeed, but the node might have been bootstrapped with an old vagrant box.